# What should be the value of max_gram and min_gram in Elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a question regarding ngram configurations. Elastic search documentation says

> It usually makes sense to set min_gram and max_gram to the same value.

Perhaps, too much of difference between min and max grams will increase the index storage.

But there are many blogs which are using max_gram as 8 or 20 to get higher accurate results.

I am confused between the two. Which should be the one to use?
What are pros and cons of both?

Note: My use case deals with indexing of article. Article content is usually of size 150KB.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analyze your search query. Find what type of like query is coming frequently, what is maximum length of search phrase and minimum length, is it case sensitive? Which is the field, Which having similar data? If data is similar, It will not take more storage.

You need to analyze your data and their relationship among them. Analyze your query behavior. Know your search query . Once you have all these information, You can take better decision or you can find some better way to solve it.

This article can help you: https://medium.com/@ashishstiwari/what-should-be-the-value-of-max-gram-and-min-gram-in-elasticsearch-f091404c9a14